# Accessing index in array I pushed to is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a web-app and have something like this:

```
this.arr = [];

(async function f() {
    try {
        const response = await this.myService.getData();
        const data = response.data;
        data.forEach((entry) => {
            this.arr.push(new MyObject(entry.valueOne, entry.valueTwo));
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}).call(this);
```

Now when I query `this.arr` I get the following output:

```
[]
0: Object { valueOne: "foo", valueTwo: "bar" }
1: Object { valueOne: "foobar", valueTwo: "foo" }
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
```

So try to log only the first element via

```
this.console.log(this.arr[0]);
```

and I get

```
TypeError: this.arr[0] is undefined
```

I think the problem is, that I push elements to an empty array, because when I create the array by hand like

```
console.log(
    [
        {name: "foo", description: "bar"},
        {name: "foobar", description: "foo"},
    ]
);
```

I get the following output:

```
(2) […]
0: Object { name: "foo", description: "bar"}
1: Object { name: "foobar", description: "foo"}
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
```

Almost the same, except that the length of the hand-generated array is displayed in the brackets.

Comment: Can you add a running snippet please?

Comment: can you please check and share what's contain in your **this.arr** ?

Comment: `console.log(this.arr);` logs the array, which later gets updated with new data, and the console shows the data. `console.log(this.arr[0]);` logs the first value in the array, which is undefined at the time, and since it isn't a reference, when the array changes, the log doesn't.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I tried to, but it does not make that much sense, because most of the data is fetched async. Injecting more sample data would destroy the actual code, in my opinion.

Comment: @PrAtikLochawala the second code snipped shows the content of ```this.arr```

Comment: @Andi Actually injecting data will not destoy the code. Is a really good practice as is some way of having unit tests. Tests where you can mock data and only run part of the code that you want to test. You don't need to run all the code to just test some part of it as long as you can mock part of the code.

Comment: @Andi If you read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development you will get the idea. Is a must-read if you want to create good code.

Comment: @Quentin that's it, thanks!